# Fetch column from result set having expression based SELECT without alias name

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, sqlplus, oracle-call-interface

This should be a Basic Question, but I was unable to answer when asked for. Sorry if it is too broad!

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT MYGROUPKEY,MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN) FROM
  MYTABLE
  GROUP BY MYGROUPKEY
) MYSUBQUERY;
```

This Query is Syntactically Valid. But how would someone fetch the second column of this resultset, if they have to attempt with some identifier? (The column was never provided with an alias). How can it be formatted in `SQL*Plus`. (`COL <column_name> FORMAT A<num>`)

Will that be first few characters of the text `MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)`.

I understand, `RDBMS` concept doesnt like this. But still why would the Database execute this SQL then? It never name the resultset's columns unless the query carry it?

Comment: How are you accessing the fetched data? Some APIs return the row as an array, so it would just be `col[1]`. If the API returns it as an associative array or hash, the key would be the whole formula `MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)`.

Comment: The main concern was usage in `SQL*Plus`, while formatting a Spooled report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implicit alias which is the expression with any whitespace removed. But as the expression contains characters which aren't invalid for an identifier it has to be quoted, as `"MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)"`. You can refer to that in an SQL*Plus `column` command too.

e.g.

```
SELECT MYGROUPKEY, "MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)" FROM
(
  SELECT MYGROUPKEY,MAX(MYCOLUMN) / MIN(MYCOLUMN)
  FROM MYTABLE
  GROUP BY MYGROUPKEY
) MYSUBQUERY;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b3e1/1).

There is a further wrinkle though. As identifieres can only be 30 characters, if the expression is longer than that the implicit alias is also too long to be referred to within the SQL itself. This would [get an ORA-00972](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b3e1/2):

```
SELECT MYGROUPKEY, "MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)*(1000/1000)" FROM
(
  SELECT MYGROUPKEY,MAX(MYCOLUMN) / MIN(MYCOLUMN) * (1000 / 1000)
  FROM MYTABLE
  GROUP BY MYGROUPKEY
) MYSUBQUERY;
```

It's better to add your own aliases, even for shorter expressions.

But you can sometimes still use the longer alias, for example through JDBC, where it appears in the metadata (as it does [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b3e1/6) as the column label). A section of a test that accesses the same data as the SQL Fiddle:

```
pStmt = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(
  "SELECT MYGROUPKEY,MAX(MYCOLUMN) / MIN(MYCOLUMN) * (1000 / 1000) "
    + "FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY MYGROUPKEY");
rSet = (OracleResultSet) pStmt.executeQuery();
OracleResultSetMetaData rsmd = (OracleResultSetMetaData) rSet.getMetaData();

for( int i=1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
  System.out.println( "Column label: " + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i));
  System.out.println( "Column Type:  " + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));
  System.out.println();
}

while (rSet.next())
{
  System.out.println("MYGROUPKEY: " + rSet.getInt("MYGROUPKEY"));
  System.out.println("MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)*(1000/1000): "
    + rSet.getInt("MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)*(1000/1000)"));
}
```

Produces output:

```
Column label: MYGROUPKEY
Column Type:  NUMBER

Column label: MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)*(1000/1000)
Column Type:  NUMBER

MYGROUPKEY: 1
MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)*(1000/1000): 2
```

Note the the column label/name reported n the metadata is the same as shown in the Fiddle, the expression with whitespace removed; and that I can use that as the argument for `getInt()` even though it's longer than 30 characters.

Comment: Thanks Alex for stopping by, The scope of this question was not Just `SQL*Plus`. But the basic of how the DBMS handles the result set. Do they even have Metadata.. etc.

Comment: No, the alias part ought to work anywhere (up to 30 chars), and you *might* be able to use longer identifiers from some clients - kind of doubt it but haven't tried. The longer column name shown in [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4b3e1/6) is from the metadata, for example. But you had also specifically mentioned formatting with `col` too so I put that in as an afterthought.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar - you can see the longer label in the metadata and can use it from JDBC; answer updated with demo. It may also be possible through OCI and even `dbms_sql`.

Comment: `+100` for your involvement, patience and intelligence, Sir! So, Shall we conclude like, the `ResultSet` itself bear the entire expression text as the name in metadata. Only in usage of `SQL` the _30 character_ restriction pops-in. So it's something to deal with _internals_ of Oracle's SQL processing.? I went mad on thinking this..

Comment: The 30-character limit is on the identifier length; it's only when you're using it as an identifier within SQL that it's a problem (ORA-00972). Well, clients and drivers may impose their own limits as well, and there's probably some limit (4K?) even in the metadata...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the expression is less than 30 characters

```
SQL> column "MAX(MYCOLUMN)/MIN(MYCOLUMN)" format <<some format>>
```

should work.  You can realistically look at the raw column header in SQL*Plus (before applying any formatting) to see what the assigned alias is.  Depending on the actual expression, there can be various rules applied-- eliminating spaces, for example, and limiting the expression to 30 characters.  It's generally easier to copy & paste from SQL*Plus and surround the assigned alias with double quotes.

Comment: Justin, Thanks for your feedback. The scope of this question is broader than just _SQL*Plus_. I was trying to understand how the metadata of this resultset would be!